# add custom messages in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to add some  messages in my stored procedure according to if else condition how can i do that. the issue is i have three tables team , account and user. i want to delete the teamA in team table only on the condition if there is not any account and user is related to that team. i have the stored procedure which is working fine but i want to check the condition and want to add some custom messages using if else . please help here is my code.

```
Create PROCEDURE sp_DeleteTeam

@pTeamId int
 AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   update t
   set t.Deleted =1
   from Team t
   where t.TeamId = @pTeamId
   And Not Exists (Select 1 from [User] where TeamId = @pTeamId)

   And Not Exists (Select 1 from Account where TeamId = @pTeamId)
END
```

Comment: Kindly dont use `sp_` prefix in Stored Procedure names its System Default Procedures Name prefix.

Comment: @Rajesh thanku for ur information. i am not using this prefix in my query. for better understanding i have mentioned it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the prefix sp_ for user stored procedures as that is reserved for system procs.

Below is an example that returns the message using RAISERROR.  A severity of 11 or higher as in this example will raise an exception in the application.  Severity of 10 or lower will generate an informational message.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DeleteTeam @pTeamId int
AS
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @Message varchar(2047);

        UPDATE  t
        SET     t.Deleted = 1
        FROM    Team t
        WHERE   t.TeamId = @pTeamId
                AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                 FROM   [User]
                                 WHERE  TeamId = @pTeamId )
                AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                 FROM   Account
                                 WHERE  TeamId = @pTeamId );

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN
                IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                                FROM    Team
                                WHERE   TeamId = @pTeamId )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Message = 'does not exist in Team table';
                    END;
                IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                            FROM    [User]
                            WHERE   TeamId = @pTeamId )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Message = COALESCE(@Message + ', ', '')
                            + 'already exists in User table';
                    END;
                IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                            FROM    Account
                            WHERE   TeamId = @pTeamId )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Message = COALESCE(@Message + ', ', '')
                            + 'already exists in Account table';
                    END;
                SET @Message = 'Team %d: ' + @Message
                RAISERROR(@Message, 11, 0, @pTeamId);
            END;
    END;
```

Comment: hi sir and how can i set the value like
t.Deleted = 1,
t.LastUpdatedOn = getDate(),
t.LastUpdatedBy = ????

from team t , i want lastUpdatedBy column is filled with UserId which is in User Table 

what i have try  it so far

Deleted = 1,
 LastUpdatedOn = GetDate(),
 LastUpdatedBy = 1 

" ihave put this value hard coded"" please help

Comment: You mention you want the LastUpdatedBy value from the User table, but the UPDATE will occur only of the TeamId is not in that table.  I suggest you post another question with `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data, and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below SP to use print or select message.

```
Create PROCEDURE sp_DeleteTeam

@pTeamId int
 AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF ((NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 FROM [User] WHERE TeamId = @pTeamId)) AND (Not EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 FROM Account WHERE TeamId = @pTeamId)))
   BEGIN
     UPDATE T
     SET T.Deleted = 1
     FROM Team t
     WHERE T.TeamId = @pTeamId

     SELECT 'Not exist - Table updated' AS Message
     --PRINT 'Not exist - Table updated'
   END
  ELSE 
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'Already exist - Table not updated.' AS Message
    --PRINT 'Already exist - Table not updated.'
  END
END
```

Comment: hi sir and how can i set the value like t.Deleted = 1, t.LastUpdatedOn = getDate(), t.LastUpdatedBy = ???? from team t , i want lastUpdatedBy column is filled with UserId which is in User Table what i have try it so far Deleted = 1, LastUpdatedOn = GetDate(), LastUpdatedBy = 1 " ihave put this value hard coded"" please help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you just want to see if it executed sucessfully. If the stored Procedure is being called In some Applciation, At the end, Give a select statement as

```
SELECT 'Your message' AS Message
```

Then in application store the result in Dataset and retrieve your message,

If you are not using it in any application, then simply use

```
print 'your message'
```

OR may be try to be more specific and elaborate you problem a bit clearly.